# Wine right click open is different to terminal "wine appname"

Tags: wine

I have an application (Star Trek Bridge Commander) which runs fine on Wine when I navigate to its directory and 'open with -> Wine Windows Program Loader' from the right click menu. Unfortunately, it quits with a runtime error if I try to use 'wine (path)' or 'wine start (path)' in the terminal. This is a problem because I am trying to make a custom shortcut (.desktop file) to open it.

Thankyou for any assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

```
cd
```

into the directory of the file and then run

```
wine APPNAME
```

to run your program.

For example, the following will give STBC (and many other applications) a runtime error:

```
wine /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\(x86\)/Activision/Bridge\ Commander/stbc.exe
```

The correct set of commands to use is:

```
cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\(x86\)/Activision/Bridge\ Commander

wine stbc.exe
```

This is apparently because it gives the application the correct working directory, which does not happen with the first example.

How to put the working set of commands into a single command for use in a .desktop file (shortcut), however, is something I don't know how to do, so I simply created a bash script containing both commands and linked the .desktop file to that instead.